# Vector clear vs. resize

Tags: c++

I read on the Internet that if you are clearing a `std::vector` repetitively (in a tight loop), it might be better to use `resize(0)` instead of `clear()`, as it may be faster. I am not sure about this. Does anyone have a definitive answer to this?

Comment: Can you try it both ways and tell us how it went?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume you mean `resize(0)` instead of `setsize`, and calling that instead of `clear()`, and that you're talking about `std::vector`.  IIRC a recent answer discussed this (can't find the link), and on modern STL implementations, `clear()` is likely identical to `resize(0)`.

Previously clearing a vector might have freed all its memory (ie. its capacity also falls to zero), causing reallocations when you start adding elements again, in contrast to `resize(0)` keeping the capacity so there are fewer reallocations.  However, I think in modern STL libraries there is no difference.  If you're using an old STL implementation, or you're just paranoid, `resize(0)` might be faster.

Comment: Or using MFC, it's array (ie vector) class has a setsize that its effectively a resize

Comment: I don't know about MFC's containers, the OP said vector so I assumed they meant `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Since C++11 there is a crucial difference between resize(0) and clear(). clear() is defined as being noexcept. Calling resize(0) prevents that the calling function can be made noexcept.

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be a difference between clear and resize(0) when the vector contains objects of a class that does not have a default constructor. For example, the following code will compile:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    A(int x,int y) :x(x), y(y) {}
};

int main() {
  std::vector <A> aa;

  aa.clear();
}
```

But if you substitute the `aa.clear()` by `aa.resize(0)`, you get compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
```

Comment: I suppose this is because resize needs the default constructor so it can default construct new elements if you are resizing to a size larger than the current size.

Comment: And because it needs to know how to construct A.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at Dinkumware STL source, both effectively call `erase(begin(), end());`

`clear()` is slightly more efficient, unsurprisingly., as it has just the one case to deal with. but I wouldn't expect it's measurable.

Answer (score 2):

This sound implementation specific, and is a job for you, your library and a profiler. But as I see it, I cannot see why resize(0) should be quicker when both will in effect have to call erase(begin(),end()).